# How do you safely read memory in Unix (or at least Linux)?

Tags: linux, unix, memory, readprocessmemory

I want to read a byte of memory but don't know if the memory is truly readable or not. You can do it under OS X with the vm_read function and under Windows with ReadProcessMemory or with _*try/*_catch. Under Linux I believe I can use ptrace, but only if not already being debugged.

FYI the reason I want to do this is I'm writing exception handler program state-dumping code, and it helps the user a lot if the user can see what various memory values are, or for that matter know if they were invalid.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to be fast, which is typical in code handling state dump/exception handlers, then you can put your own signal handler in place before the access attempt, and restore it after.  Incredibly painful and slow, but it is done.

Another approach is to parse the contents of /dev/proc//maps to build a map of the memory once, then on each access decide whether the address in inside the process or not.

If it were me, I'd try to find something that already does this and re-implement or copy the code directly if licence met my needs.  It's painful to write from scratch, and nice to have something that can give support traces with symbol resolution.